# AEM new Component doesn't available to use on the Component list

Tags: adobe, aem

I've followed the [AEM Custom Component tutorial](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/getting-started-wknd-tutorial-develop/project-archetype/custom-component.html?lang=en#add-the-component-to-a-page) to create a new component but after deploying the code the new component is not available on the left pallet. The name of my new component is **Spacer** and inherit from **Separator**. Also, on the template editor, I can't see the new component as well.

**Steps**

File structure: `ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/my_project/components/spacer`
[image]

`spacer/.content.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
          jcr:title="Spacer"
          jcr:description="Able to define a Spacer with pixels choice."
          sling:resourceSuperType="core/wcm/components/separator/v1/separator"
          componentGroup="My Project - Content"/>
```

`spacer/spacer.html`

```
<div data-sly-use.placeholderTemplate="core/wcm/components/commons/v1/templates.html">
</div>
<sly data-sly-call="${placeholderTemplate.placeholder @ isEmpty=true}"></sly>
```

`spacer/_cq_dialog/.content.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:granite="http://www.adobe.com/jcr/granite/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
          jcr:title="Spacer"
          sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog">
    <content
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/fixedcolumns">
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <column
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <text
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
                        fieldLabel="Text"
                        name="./text"/>
                </items>
            </column>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

Installed with: `mvn clean install -PautoInstallSinglePackage`
Result: **BUILD SUCCESS**

Component appearing on CRX:

[image]

Component not appearing on Site Edit pallet:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED**

I had to enable the new component on the Template Layout policies.

Comment: Yes few reasons if component doesnt show up: 1) Title and label of component needs to be different (wierd but true); 2) cq:dialog needs to be created; 3) Make sure template policy includes the component group or individual component.